# add_column in tibble with variable column name

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

This code doesn't work to add a column in tibble:

```
  library(tidyverse)
  df <- data.frame("Oranges" = 5)
  mycols <- c("Apples", "Bananas", "Oranges")
  add_column(df, mycols[[2]] = 7)
```

I get the error message:

```
  Error: unexpected '=' in "add_column(df, mycols[[2]] ="
```

But this code works:

```
  add_column(df, "Bananas" = 7)
```

Why?

I don't know the values of 'mycols' ahead of time.  That's why I wrote my code for it to be a variable.  Is this not possible in dplry?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use one of the two options:

```
add_column(df, "{mycols[2]}" := 7)
add_column(df, !!(mycols[2]) := 7)
```

The first one is the more preferred style now where you can use `glue` strings to create parameter names. Otherwise you can use  `!!` to inject the parameter name. Both require `:=` allows you to use variables for parameter names (which you cannot do with the `=` that's normally used when calling a function).

Comment: That worked, thank you.  I see !! and := in the help file, but I don't understand the documentation, and I've never seen them used before.  Are you able to briefly state what they do?

Comment: @Joe Take a look here: http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: @Joe "You are in an environment of spiky little programming problems, all different"

Comment: @MrFlick is there documentation on `!!`? I see `:=` at that link, but not `!!` and both of these are new tricks to me! Thanks.

Comment: @Hendy You might want to check out: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/ or https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/sec-why-how.html for more info on `!!`. You can also bring up the help page with `?"!!"`